# Generating columns in table and header for exported data file automatically

Tags: list-manipulation, arithmetic

I have a code that goes like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

const1 = 2.;
\[Kappa] = 23;

tbl = Table[{x, N[x^(1/2)], 0 x, N[x^(1/3)], 0 x, N[x^(1/4)], 0 x, 
    N[x^(1/5)], 0 x}, {x, 2, 20, 2}];

SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

newrow[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_}] := {a, b, c, (
   Sqrt[\[Pi]]*b* const1 Exp[-(b^2/(2 Sqrt[a]))])/(const1 \[Kappa]^5),
    d, e, (Sqrt[\[Pi]]*d *onst1 Exp[-(d^2/(2 Sqrt[a]))])/(
   const1 \[Kappa]^5), f, g, (
   Sqrt[\[Pi]]*f *const1 Exp[-(f^2/(2 Sqrt[a]))])/(const1 \[Kappa]^5),
    h, i, (Sqrt[\[Pi]]*h *const1 Exp[-(h^2/(2 Sqrt[a]))])/(
   const1 \[Kappa]^5)};
newtbl = Map[newrow, tbl];
headings = {"x", "real1", "imag1", "col1manipulated", "real2", 
   "imag2", "col2manipulated", "real3", "imag3", "col3manipulated", 
   "real4", "imag4", "col4manipulated"};
Export["file1.dat", Join[{headings}, newtbl]];
```

Once the table, tbl, is created, I am taking the data from each column and use it to do some arithmetic operation.

1. Now, as you can see, I have a term $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}*b*const1*e^{\frac{-b^2}{2\sqrt{a}}}}{const1*κ^5 }$ which repeats multiple time but with only one factor changing, namely, b or d or f or h. If I am writing individual terms all the times, the code becomes messy. Is there any way to simply it? E.g. define something like $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}*i*const1*e^{\frac{-i^2}{2\sqrt{a}}}}{const1*κ^5 }$ outside and call it inside every time?
2. In the code which gives me heading, I have to write **"real1","imag1","col1manipulated"** and then **"real2","imag2","col2manipulated"** so on. Is there any way to simplify this? Like to make **"real1","imag1","col1manipulated"** till **"real5","imag5","col5manipulated"** by some command and then append it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

revised

```
fun[v_] := Sqrt[\[Pi]] v const1 Exp[-b^2/(2 Sqrt[a])]/(const1 \[Kappa]^5);
newrow[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_}] := 
  {a, b, c, fun[b], d, e, fun[d], f, g, fun[f], h, i, fun[h]};
heading=Flatten[{"x", Table[str=ToString[i];
  {"real"<>str,"imag"<>str,"col"<>str<>"manipulated"},{i,1,4}]}]
```

Comment: you are almost there. In heading, I need to put "x" one and only time, which you have not done it. If I am putting it inside {"real"<>str..."manipulated"}, it is getting repeated 5 times. What more can be done?

Also kindly check the question, I made a mistake in "headings": "real3", "imag3", "col3manipulated" was missing and I have deleted "real5", "imag5", "col5manipulated". Question has been edited.

Comment: thanks you.. this is it..